# GO dynamic update queries with Gin and PGX

Tags: postgresql, go, marshalling, go-gin, pgx

I'm trying to build a web service which would receive an HTTP PATCH request to update some fields in a "users" table (so I don't know how many nor which ones have to be updated).

I decided to work with [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin) and because I'm working with Postgres, I'm using [pgx](https://github.com/jackc/pgx).

The request...

```
PATCH {{protocol}}{{host}}/update-user/USER_ID_XXX HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer : TOKEN_XXX

{
    "review_count": 2,
    "rating": 2.2,
}
```

... is handled by the Patch method

```golang
func (handler *userHandler) Patch(c *gin.Context) {
    reqBody := &users.User{}
    err := c.BindJSON(reqBody) <------ BREAKS
    if err != nil {
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, rest_errors.NewInternalServerError("JSON Binding Failed while trying to patch user", err))
        return
    }
    ...
```

The `User` struct makes uses of [pgtypes](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype). This is because, in the context of a `GET` request, if I retrieve a `User` from **Postgres** who has a `review_count` field set to null, i get an error when trying to marshal the result. So the `pgtype.Int` struct encapsulate the original value, a few other fields and contains a `MarshalJSON()` function to do the job properly ( [see the MarshalJSON function here in pgtype.Int2](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/int2.go) )

user_dto.go

```golang
type User struct {
    Id                string        `json:"id"`
    ...
    ReviewCount       pgtype.Int2   `json:"review_count"`
    Rating            float32       `json:"rating"`
    ...
}
```

Back to our `PATCH` request, the problem naturally comes in when I receive a field that is "pgtyped" like `review_count` .... Gin tries to unmarshal it and fails because it parses an `int` value and he's asked to put it into the [pgtype.Int2](https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/blob/master/int2.go) struct. So when I call `err := c.BindJSON(reqBody)` I get this error

> "json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field
> User.ReviewCount of type pgtype.Int2"

I never had to implement this kind of feature before and I must confess that I know nothing about the "best options" if only I knew one that is working  :D

Comment: While pgtype.Int2 does have a MarshalJSON method it's missing the corresponding UnmarshalJSON method. BindJSON does unmarshaling, not marshaling. That's why it doesn't know how to unmarshal `int` into `struct`. Some other pgtype int types (int4 & int8) do have UnmarshalJSON. Why int2 doesn't I can't tell.

Comment: Man, you're right! I didn't see it. Well, now I get my object. I'll post an issue in their Github repo just in case it's an oversight.

Comment: The unmarshall func has been added in the last commit https://github.com/jackc/pgtype/commit/25558de3bd1bd2441cd3442394502b567ea94fbe